# Control language/localization in ExtLib controls?

Tags: localization, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I am currently creating a web layout for an old database based on XPages. The users are Danish - and I want to ensure that they see a correct layout of dates and Danish labels on the pagers etc.

For the standard pager I am using the "custom" type and translate the "Previous" and "Next" labels (put it on a custom control and reuse that on all the pages). I did try to set the language on the pager, however, that does not change anything...?

Well, now I am also using the "pagerExpand" control from the Update Pack (official Extension Library). It shows correct labels based on the language in the browser. Since I cannot be sure that the language in the browser has been set correctly, I want to control that. How can I control these labels?

In the bigger perspective, I want to be able to control language in an application as a whole... (for other future applications)

/John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a XSnippet for controlling the language of a XPage application:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xpages-localization-setter

To change the language in a XPage manually, you can do this in SSJS with this function:

```
view.setLocale( )
```

Hope this helps

Sven

**EDIT:**
To set the correct language, you have to use *java.util.Locale*. To set the language f.e. to danish, add this to *beforeRenderResponse*:

```
var locale = new java.util.Locale( "da" );
view.setLocale( locale );
```

Comment: If I understand your snippet (and the other article) correctly, putting something like: view.setLocale("da"); into the "beforeRenderResponse" event of the XPage should set the language correctly to Danish? However, that does not work...?

Comment: I have added an example how to set the language in my answer.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked - and looking at the argument lidt of view.setLocal() I can see that you are right - it needs a "Locale" type of object - and not a String. My fault... Thank you very much for your inside info ;-)