# FileDownload control - how to format dates (created and lastmodified)

Tags: download, xpages, date-format

I am using a FileDownload control to show a list of attachments from a Notes document.

The dates are shown as: dd/MM/yy hh.mm - and since my users are Danish I would like to show the dates in the format: dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm.

That is pretty simple if you use a SimpleDateFormater. In SSJS that would look like:

```
var date:Date = new Date(aFile.getCreated());
if(date==null) return date;
return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm").format(date);
```

In the FileDownload control you can compute the value of "createdValue" property. However, the control expects an object of type "Date" which does not allow for the formating in the above example (it just throws an Error 500).

Any suggestions?

/John

Comment: Normally NotesDateTime class is a better solution for Xpage, Why are everyone using other classes? If we are in CSJS then it is okay. But for our xpages, NotesDateTime is powerful to change its format. Try to do ot NotesDateTime.

Comment: You mentioned Error 500, Means exactly what error you got?

Comment: Well, the control expects a Date object. It shows a correct formatted date if I just put "new Date()" into the formula. So, I am bound to that. If I try to return any other type than a "Date" I get the Error 500. The point is that it is a "built-in" control that I cannot find any documentation on how to control the format....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already found that the **createdValue** property expects a java.util.Date object, so the only way to change how that is formatted is by changing the browser locale used by the XPage (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460426/control-language-localization-in-extlib-controls)). Using the standard download control you can get a handle on every file by adding the **var="file"** attribute to it and use that in the createdValue property:

```
createdValue="new Date(file.getCreated());"
```

If you want to have more control on the list of files you could use a repeat control and bind it to the list of files from a RichText item:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="file" disableOutputTag="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getAttachmentList("files")}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:text escape="false" disableTheme="true" xp:key="header">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[<table><tbody>]]>
            </xp:this.value></xp:text>
        <xp:text escape="false" disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[</tbody></table>]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{file.name}"></xp:text>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var date:Date = new Date(file.getCreated());
    return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm").format(date);}]]></xp:this.value>
      </xp:text>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xp:repeat>
```

By the way: another a disadvantage of the default download control is that it adds a content-disposition header to every link, so the browsers always asks you if you want to save or open the file instead of opening images (for instance) directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  As you have seen, I am already setting the locale correctly to "Danish", however, the format returned by the FileDownload control is not the format that we use in Denmark :-/  - otherwise, I would have been done some time ago ;-)  Perhaps it was not clear, but the formula I mentioned was indeed the formula in the createdValue property, where I have to return a Date.  If I cannot control the format to be correct, then obviously, I can code everything myself (as you have given a good example of) - however, I had hoped that the controls would be able to do this trick

Comment: In my case the standard content-disposition actually works fine ;-)  But I do appreciate that could be a problem in other situations.

Comment: Well, I ended up coding the list myself (along the lines you laid out above). Thanks for the help :-)